# How to tell if a phone is rooted?

Tags: htc-desire, root-access, unrevoked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if I have root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-root)

Is there a way to tell if an Android phone is rooted? Where can you find this information in the phone?

I used Unrevoked to root my HTC Desire (GSM) and I had the tool set to disable the phone security as well. But when I start the HBOOT menu it still says S-ON on top of the screen. Shouldn't that say S-OFF now?

Maybe Unrevoked failed to set S-OFF, but managed to root the phone? It has definitely changed the recovery system, because now it says ClockWorkMod Recovery. There is also a new app called Superuser Permissions. Does that mean it's been rooted?

I could try to install some app that requires root, but I thought I would hold off with that since I have just completely re-flashed it and don't want to clutter it with any bloatware until I have set up A2SD+ and partitioned my SD card.

I'm also curious as to why it didn't set the security flag to S-OFF. Would I need to use AlphaRev for this now? And can I skip this part, and still install A2SD+ and partition my SD card? What I'm asking is this: is S-OFF a requirement for A2SD+ and partitioning the SD card and messing around with things like partitioning, /system and Dalvik cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell if an Android phone is rooted?

The easiest way of root checking is to use program [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it should say S-OFF when you boot. However, the fact that it has CWM Recovery is a good sign.

[Google play has many apps that will check root](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20checker&c=apps) for you. Give one of them a try.

Answer (score 0):

Some phone rooted will show new application(SuperSU, Superuser, or else) but you didn't install it before. It's easiest way to know your phone was rooted or not.