# How can I root the Amazon FireTV?

Tags: rooting

I would like to root my Amazon FireTV so I can sideload applications on it. Like XBMC (Kodi), Google Play, Google Play Movies.

My FireTV OS version is 51.1.1.0_user_511070220. Can I root it? What are the steps to root it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Important: Not all versions of the FireTV can be rooted. See below if your version can be rooted.**

For a list that may be more up-to-date, see [AFTVNews software list](http://www.aftvnews.com/software/).

> Due to recent software updates that block rooting, some Fire TVs
>   cannot be rooted. To know if your Fire TV can be rooted, check your
>   software version by going to: Settings > System > About on your Fire
>   TV.

- 51.1.4.3_user_514020320

  - Released: 2/5/2015
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.4.2_user_514015320

  - Released: 12/15/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.4.1_user_514013920

  - Released: 11/18/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.4.0_user_514005520

  - Released: 10/23/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.4.0_user_514006420

  - Released: 10/23/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.3.0_user_513010720

  - Released: 10/26/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.3.0_user_513011820

  - Released: 9/25/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- 51.1.3.0_user_513011520

  - Released: 9/13/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
- **51.1.2.0_user_512073320**

  - Released: 8/13/2014
  - Rootable: **NO**
  - Notes: As of 1/1/2015, all updates after this date have not been rootable.
- 51.1.1.0_user_511070220

  - Released: 7/9/2014
  - Rootable: **YES**
- 51.1.1.0_user_511069920

  - Released: 6/25/2014
  - Rootable: **YES**
- 51.1.0.2_user_510058520

  - Released: 4/29/2014
  - Rootable: **YES**
- 51.1.0.1_user_510055620

  - Released: 4/7/2014
  - Rootable: **YES**
- 51.1.0_user_510047320

  - Released: 4/2/2014
  - Rootable: **YES**

---

If you made it this far, congratulations! You have a build of FireOS that is rootable. Let's proceed

1. Download [TowelRoot](https://towelroot.com/) by clicking on the Red Icon
   [image: TowelRoot]
2. Download [SuperSU Apk](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) - We need the APK because we do not have Google Play - [XDA Thread for SuperSU](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053)
3. Side load the applications on to the FireTV - This is beyond this question, I may do a Q&A for this in the future. In the mean time, look for [adbFire](http://www.jocala.com/adbfire.html) to sideload the apps or [Ask a Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for help with this step.
4. Launch `towelroot` from your FireTV application menu
5. Use the remote and click `make it ra1n` button
   [image]
6. Wait for `towelroot`to finish.

   - You may need to reboot.
7. Launch SuperSU
8. Update `su` binary if you are asked.
9. Verify you have root access - see [how can I tell if I have root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-root)

   - this can be done from a console/terminal window and connect to the FireTV via adb

     adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555
     adb shell su
10. You should be promted on your FireTV with a *Grant* request
    [image]