# Rooting/unrooting my device under warranty

Tags: rooting, 9.0-pie, unrooting, warranty

A couple of weeks ago I bought one of those indestructible type of phone, from a manufacturer that also produces excavators and whose name starts with a C and ends with AT.

In the terms and conditions of their "Limited warranty" I read that it is not allowed to root the device, or else the warranty will no longer be valid. Nothing new to me in general. However the way they described it leaves room for debate when it comes down to it.

They state that the terms and conditions **do not apply** when the **defect is caused by**:

> Performance issues or incompatibilities caused by editing of the
>   registry settings, modifications of the operating software including
>   but not limited to rooting the device or 3rd party application
>   downloads.

So I contacted their support. This is what I wrote the manufacturer about:

> I have a question about the terms of warranty on the C^A^T S52. I read
>   that rooting the phone could be a reason for C4T to terminate the
>   warranty.
>
> Is this the case under all circumstances, or only when the phone would
>   defect as a result of the rooting?
>
> And if I read everything in literal terms, does it more or less say
>   that everything that has not been mentioned is allowed? In other
>   words, if I root the phone, and perhaps) have to claim warranty, can I
>   just unroot before sending it to you in order for the warranty to
>   remain valid?

The manufacturer responded with:

> Yes, rooting the device will void the warranty under all
>   circumstances. The Repair Centre will know if you rooted the device or
>   not even if you unroot it before sending in for repair/claim the
>   warranty.

Does anyone have knowledge of how the repair centre can determine whether a device has been rooted/unrooted and if there's a way that I can bypass it? Additionally, I would like to know if anyone has had any experience with repairing a unit under warranty, despite the fact that the unit was rooted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do people at service center check if the phone is rooted or not?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160113/how-do-people-at-service-center-check-if-the-phone-is-rooted-or-not)

Comment: Second part of the question - it is again OEM based. I got a rooted phone repaired under warranty but then OEM wasn't against rooting

Comment: @beeshyams That didn't answer my completely, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I find it so hard to believe that it's not possible, in the end it's all ones and zeros right

Comment: @beeshyams Well, they kind of explicitly told me the warranty will void if I do root my phone... But if you read the terms of warranty, it actually says that the warranty will be voided if rooting caused the defect. A judge would rule in my favour if it comes down to it. I just don't get the point of prohibiting me to root my own phone, which I payed a lot for. I mean, how many people will fry their phone because of root...

Comment: What confuses me much more is that "3rd party application downloads" would void the warranty. Are they saying "thou shalt not install apps"? Wouldn't that render their terms void?