# Does rooting mean I will always run my device as root?

Tags: rooting, root-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly does “root” user access/account works? Do all applications run as root on my phone after rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16367/how-exactly-does-root-user-access-account-works-do-all-applications-run-as-ro)

I understand the root user under Linux and the goal of rooting an Android device. Though, when people say "rooting", does it mean I will always use my device as root? Or just while I apply my changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Rooting in that case means that apps are able to request root. If they do so, then usually a pop-up appears asking for your permission.

Comment: It also means you are able to use `su` and `sudo` in a terminal emulator. Although I guess that's really just prompting the emulator to request root.