# Browser's webview.db doesn't store Hotmail password, but it can still auto login. Why?

Tags: security, browser, password, hotmail

On my rooted Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1, stock browser doesn't store any password for Hotmail, but whenever I open Hotmail, it logins automatically.

I checked `data/data/com.android.browser/webview.db`, the `password` table has a row for Hotmail like below:

`host = https://login.live.com, username = blank, password = blank`

Why does it still auto login Hotmail even though the password is not stored?

Comment: Just a guess: cookies?