# what changes are done, while rooting an android phone?

Tags: rooting

I've rooted my phone running 4.2.2 jb through computer (I tried all mobile rooting apps but nothing worked for me) 
I want to know what's the difference rooting program did?has it switched me to root user? To do that something has to be changed. Then what is it?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times. Over 1000 questions are associated with the tag [rooting] you added to your own question. Have you scanned any of them for background? Especially [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device) one.

Comment: Also see [How exactly does "root" user access/account works? Do all applications run as root on my phone after rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16367)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a binary named `su` to your phone's operating system file. Android is based on Linux OS. Not all users can do everything they want in Linux. For example, an app in your phone, can't access to another app's data. It doesn't have the necessary permissions as a normal user. All apps you install are assigned a UID (User ID) by the system. There is however, another user in Linux OS that can execute all commands and can access everywhere and has all permissions. That is the `root` user (UID 0). When you *root* your phone, you add a binary and an app to manage it. (usually SuperSU) When you grant an app root access, it can execute commands and have permissions it normally can't. **So beware of the apps you grant root access to.**

Answer (score -1):

No Much Changes are Done on rooting the Android Device the User can access  even the Android OS files which are responsible for All operations so This helps us to uninstall bloatware and it can also make the system potentially vulnerable i.e. Many Apps can easily Exploit the root access to spy on Your Phone even key logs can be sent over internet when the device is rooted so, if you know what thing you are messing up just go ahead else i'll better say you to stay **On Unrooted mode** and its true You can get the most from Android after rooting your Phone !!  ;) **Root With Caution and if you are really ready to face the consequences ** Some in complete Roots may make your phone cause Boot loop i.e.To stay on boot screen itself To be short this is like the su command in Linux Systems !  :)

**2nd** : 
      You can even Root your Computer without Computer its not that always a Computer is needed to root the phone Except for some Phones :)

Comment: please rephrase your answer, use punctuation and try to make your second point clearer. Personally I have no idea what you are trying to describe