# What do "NAND", "ROM" and "to flash" mean?

Tags: custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc)

I'd like to know the meaning of the following terms:

- What does NAND mean?
- What is a ROM? Is it a custom OS?
- What does "to flash" refer to (as in, to flash a ROM)? Does it mean to copy?

Answer (score 0):

A **Nandroid** backup is a backup of your phone that is an exact image of the state of your phone. So you could make an exact copy of your current phone, then do major changes to it, and then restore to your previous backup by **flashing** the backup back to the phone. **Flashing** means to copy or to install.... you are essentially wiping the device and restoring a previous state (a backup) or you are flashing a new **ROM** (which is a custom version of Android).

More info: [I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting), [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc) , etc.

Comment: It sounds like the OP actually wants to know what "NAND" means, not "nandroid" (could be wrong, but that's how the question is posed).

Comment: I've integrated this into the wiki question -- no need to split them up, IMO.  Have an upvote though ;)

Comment: @eldareathis hmm, usually nand refers to nandroid backups (in the realm of Android).... I didn't think he meant the boolean logic NAND :)

Comment: Neither did I. I meant [NAND memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#NAND_flashs), which is where "nandroid" gets its name from and is also within the realm of Android.