# I want to root my phone

Tags: rooting

Can anyone tell me what is the easiest way to root my phone.
I have a Samsung galaxy note 2.
And what does it mean to flash a new Rom?

Comment: Also see: [What is the difference between: Rooting, Jailbreak, ROM, Mod, etc.?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-the-difference-between-rooting-jailbreak-rom-mod-etc), [What do “NAND”, “ROM” and “to flash” mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20656/what-do-nand-rom-and-to-flash-mean)

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to root your device.

I just did a quick search and came up with this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2143479. Try following that and see if it works (the process I took for rooting my tablet was pretty much just 'try every guide that I can find until something works', so really just keep looking through guides on the internet).

The term ROM is traditionally used to mean Read Only Memory. Over time, it has come to mean (in the Android world) the OS that your device runs, because the OS is thought to be read-only by some people. Flashing a new ROM just means replacing stock Android with something else.

Comment: What are the pro's to rooting? I wanted to do it so I could use a backup app titanium.

Comment: @user46862 Please take a look at our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), which will answer most of your questions.

Comment: The biggest (and really, only) cons that I know of are 1) voiding the warranty (but they usually don't check to see if it's rooted when you send it for repair), and 2) the slight possibility of bricking your device. As for the second part, I have done everything short of intentionally bricking my Android (including boot loops, rooting, custom ROMS, custom recovery) and it still works fine.

Comment: As for pros, you have full access to everything. Enough said. ;)