# How do I install a custom ROM?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, root-access

I  have a sprint s3 and I just rooted my phone and it was done correct. my question is do I need to download the roms to my computer first then copy to my phone.I have been trying from my phone. it downloads but can't open. help please. thanks

Comment: See also: [I've rooted my phone. Now what? What do I gain from rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Installing a custom ROM implies a number of steps:

1. Root your phone.
2. Flash a custom recovery ([4ext](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ext.recovery.control&hl=en) or [CWM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ClockworkMod_Recovery)).
3. Store on you sd card a downloaded custom ROM.
4. Reboot your phone into recovery, select the desired ROM and flash it.
5. Reboot and have fun.

**Note**: Please **BACKUP your data** before doing anything! Better safe than sorry.

[This article](http://theunlockr.com/2012/08/29/how-to-load-a-custom-rom-on-an-android-device/) explains in detail each step.
You can also find a lot of info about flashing, custom ROMs and all sort of things on [**XDA** developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a proper recovery like CWM or TWRP

Download the ROM file off XDA, make sure you download a file made for only your system.

Wipe date and do a factory reset

(optional: make a backup of your stock ROM)

Flash your ROM

Wipe date and factory reset, reboot and $$profit$$