# rooting android phone

Tags: rooting, root-access

Hi guys. I am new to Android. I wanted to know, when I root my phone, will I be receiving pure android os, and get constant update whenever Google releases new OS? Also, will I be able to revert back to the original UI of the manufacturer?

Answer (score 3):

Rooting your phone doesn't change what OS it runs. It just means you have root access to the existing OS. Changing the OS (i.e. flashing a [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom)) is a separate thing.

See also the answers to [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean) and [I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting)

Comment: ...and follow up to the [root tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/root/info) as well as [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) for details :)