# Can't root Galaxy 5830i

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-ace

A year ago I bought a Galaxy ACE GT-5830i which came with Gingerbread 2.3.6, recently I wanted to root it, I tried following the instructions in [Root,Unroot,CWM,and how to Flash Galaxy Ace S5830i](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1552792), without success.

I wiped cache, Dalvik cache, rooted again, again and again but did not work.

After the root process I found the *Superuser* icon on the launcher, I checked for root and even tried to use *link2sd* and nothing. I tried to update the superuser app from Google play and ... nothing. How to root this device?

Comment: I tried to Root my Samsung galaxy s5830i. I followed the instruction on the xda developers and successfully rooted my S5830i without any problem and it works!.
Try this at your own risk.
Here is the link:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1552792
Using SD card as Internal memory:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2142844

Answer (score -1):

If you see the superuser icon then your phone is rooted. See this post to know what to do after root:[I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting)