# How to remove unwanted system applications in Andriod on Samsung Tab 4 T231?

Tags: applications, samsung, delete, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

Several apps come preloaded on the tablet and I want to trash them. What's the way out?

Comment: You must have root permissions to remove systems apps. Is you device rooted?

Comment: @Lucky I don't know. How to find out?

Comment: Easiest way is to download Root Checker from the playstore. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en

Edit. Also not all preloaded apps are "system" apps. Some of the preloaded apps can be removed without root.

Comment: [What does “to root a phone” mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/249/27149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall apps. Open ***Settings*** and find the ***Application Manager*** and select the app you want to uninstall. Then you will see the option to uninstall it. If you only see disable, that means it's a system app and will require root to remove.

[What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean/)
[How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)
[I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting)

***WARNING: Removing system apps can impact your system. Certain apps need each other to function.***

***DISCLAIMER*: ROOTING YOUR PHONE WILL PROBABLY VOID YOUR WARRANTY FROM BOTH THE CARRIER AND THE MANUFACTURER.**

Comment: I checked w.r.t Dropbox. There is an option of "Uninstall updates", "disable", "force stop".  nothing more than that.

Comment: That means Samsung labels that as a system app. Which will require root to remove. You can always disable it to hide it from the app drawer.