# S7 Archive all apps & settings info for re-install?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

Is there a way to save all my Galaxy S7 App List, settings on/off and user settings in a cloud file to allow me to do a factory reset and import my archive file back to my existing phone?  Something like Google Takeout?

Answer (score 0):

3 Methods

1 = Steps:

1.Root The device.Check if that is your mobile.Root methods made for one variant S7 may not work for other variants.

2.Install Titanium Backup.Backup all the apps that you need.Even settings can be backed.

3.Do a factory reset.Come back.Install Titanium backup again(If not rooted rot again) and reinstall.

2= Steps:

1.Root

2.Install TWRP and make a backup of whole device from recovery.

3 = Steps:

1.Do the factory reset and let it Go

Refer To this:[Uses of roots.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what-what-do-i-gain-from-rooting)